# Multiple properties to Grid background like ImageSource and Brush

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an XAML code with binding to property MainImage:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding MainImage}"/>
  </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

MainImage is a ImageSource property. But, now I want to set simple Brush background of grid to. Application is using ImageSource, if there is  an image, otherwise app have to set simple Brush color. There is the problem with covertation from Brush to ImageSource, if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the OnLoaded event and check for nulls and change it that way.  Unless you want to create an image and then paint it a certain color and return that as an image source.  I don't think there are any fallbacks unless you roll your own.

---

```
<Grid x:Name="my_grid" Loaded="my_grid_Loaded">
  <Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding MainImage}"/>
  </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

---

```
private void my_grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    Grid g = sender as Grid;
    System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush ib = g.Background as ImageBrush;                    
    if (ib.ImageSource == null)
    {
        g.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.MYCOLOR);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, but I am using ViewModel(MVVM)... And I don't need to set method in code-behind of view.

Comment: Like I said you can always create a Bitmap fill it with some color and set your image source that way if it fails to load your first image.  But if you want a XAML solution then why not just create another grid that is ZINDEX lower than the top one with your background color?

Comment: Your second idea has rights to alive, but I don't know, how the second grid will affect to application performance on low memory devices...

Answer (score 1):

If your image is not transparent, I would simply create different Grid or even Rectangle, make it full screen and with color. If there is image available, then it will just cover the color and done.